# Swift move image from right to left than from left to right

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I want to make an animation that move a background image from right to left than left to right.
I use this code but not works

```
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: .repeat ,animations: { () -> Void in
                imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -imageView.frame.width + self.view.bounds.width, y: 0)
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 1, options: .repeat ,animations: { () -> Void in
                    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: +imageView.frame.width - self.view.bounds.width, y: 0)

                })

            })
```

Comment: Please check this one:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55196234/i-want-create-a-collectionview-for-images-with-auto-scrolling-like-loop/55196308#55196308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved with this

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 30.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {

                imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -imageView.frame.width + self.view.bounds.width, y: 0)

            }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code if you want to use the legacy `animate(withDuration:animations:)` API. However, you need to wait for the first animation to be finished - this means you have to use the `completion` block.
However, your value for `translationX` does not makes sense as well.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -self.imageView.frame.width, y: 0)
        }) { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
                self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }
        }
```

I would strongly recommend having a look at the "new" way of doing Animations: `UIViewPropertyAnimator`(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator)